# BDE and AZURE SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, delphi, bde

We are looking at migrating one of our Delphi application from a local MS SQL Server to an Azure hosted SQL Server.  We have created the SQL Server on Azure (e.g. myserver.database.windows.net), and published a database to this server.

We opened the firewall on Asure and are able to connect Management Studio to the database and server. Our application uses the BDE to connect to SQL using the MSSQL driver.

When it tries to connect it returns an error that it cannot find the server

> Cannot locate or connect to SQL server.
>   Unable to connect: SQL Server is unavailable or does not exist.

We have tried to prefix the database name with tcp: and add the SQL Port 1433 which seemed to be a work around for ADO connection.

Has anyone been able to connect the BDE to an Azure database? Is the BDE just too old?

Comment: Well, iirc the BDE had been obsolete for over a decade before Azure first appeared.  Why would anyone even try using the BDE to connect to it?

Comment: @MartynA Almost two decades now...

Comment: Even if it's possible: 1) BDE does not scale well. 2) You're going to but your head against subtle differences in different technologies with different design principles. 3) You'll probably be bound to subset of functionality that you can get working. 4) Probably most important - your support base will be non-existent.

Answer (score -1):

BDE is not supported anymore. In Delphi XE2 (which is what I use), I believe the alternative are dbGO with ODBC Ole DB Provider. Maybe the new FireDAC have a more specialized connectivity to Azure.